# How to change border color of material ui Rating stars

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-functional-component

I need to change the border color of stars in material ui Rating cause my background color is black and I can't see nothing when the star is empty !

code:

```
import Rating from '@material-ui/lab/Rating';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    '& > * + *': {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
     
    },
  
  },
 
}));
```

in the functional component :

```
<div className={classes.root}>
                  <Rating name="half-rating-read" defaultValue={finalAverage} precision={0.5} readOnly />
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to import an icon with border for empty one like `StarBorderIcon` and add it like this:

```
import Rating from "@material-ui/lab/Rating";
import StarBorderIcon from "@material-ui/icons/StarBorder";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",

    "& > * + *": {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(1)
    }
  },
  emptyStar: {
    color: "white"
  }
}));
const Star = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Rating
        name="half-rating-read"
        defaultValue={3.5}
        precision={0.5}
        readOnly
        emptyIcon={
          <StarBorderIcon fontSize="inherit" className={classes.emptyStar} />
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Star;
```

[image: Edit friendly-framework-uyfj9]